# PowerShell script won't run as local user or administrator

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, windows-server-2012

I have a very small PowerShell script to reboot a given service. Unfortunately, I'm unsure why it's not working properly. It is executable, but it won't stop the requested service; neither is it executing the functions on the other 2 lines.

Here's the script:

```
# Stop the "serviceName" service
Stop-Service -Name "serviceName" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Wait for 10 seconds
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

# Start the "serviceName" service
Start-Service -Name "serviceName"
```

I tried to execute the script from my `.\Users\me\Desktop\` using PowerShell running as admin, with no luck.

Comment: Remove `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` if you want to find out why

Comment: I think I was trying to suppress the error message, which is not required in this case, I also tried -Force to bypass dependencies but that wasn't really needed either.

Comment: Nice, feel free to post an answer below :)

Comment: Try `-ErrorAction Continue` and share full error message, please.

Comment: PowerShell cmdlets has such a verbose syntax, that there is not much use in adding the comments you've done in the script :)

Answer (score 0):

removing "-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue" from the second line worked.